# WordPress: update_option, don't update empty options?

Tags: theme-options, updates

How would I go about not letting empty data into wordpress?

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name'] as  $post_eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name):
if(empty($post_eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name)): 
    echo 'empty';
else: 
    update_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $_POST);
    $eirepanel_inline_ads_options = get_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options');
endif; 
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More importantly, you should not let *untrusted, unsanitized $_POST data* into WordPress.

But I think the issue is that you're updating the option with the entire $_POST data, instead of the appropriate array key:

```
update_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $_POST);
```

Should probably be something like:

```
update_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $_POST['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name']);
```

Are your Plugin options discrete (one DB entry per option), or an options array?

**EDIT**

Since you're using an options array, the correct approach would be:

1. Define an array to hold the `$_POST` data ( `$input = array()` )
2. Define an array to get the current settings from the DB  ( `$valid_input = array()` )
3. Sanitize the `$_POST` data
4. Update the `$valid_data` array with the sanitized `$input` array
5. Pass the updated `$valid_data` back to the DB

e.g.

```
$input = ( isset( $_POST ) ? $_POST : false );
$valid_input = get_option( 'eirepanel_inline_ads_options' );

foreach ( $input as $key ) {
   // sanitize data here
}

$valid_input = array_merge( $valid_input, $input );

update_option( 'eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $valid_input );
```

Just quick and dirty, but should give you an idea.

Also: using the Settings API would be especially helpful here.

Comment: No, I am using an options array. I know I could do it this way: "update_option('eirepanel_inline_ads_options', $_POST['eirepanel_inline_ads_options_name']);" but I like my original method. Any further help would be very much appreciated

Comment: See update to my answer, above.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your response to @Chip's suggestions, I'd advise you name your inputs like so;

```
<input type="text" name="eire[option_key_name]" value="hello world" />
<input type="text" name="eire[option_key_another]" />
<input type="text" name="eire[nasty_key_possibility]" />
```

Then in your code;

```
$options = shortcode_atts( array(
    'option_key_name' => 'default value',
    'option_key_another' => 'foobar'
), ( array ) $_POST['eire'] );
```

`$options` will now only contain the explicit keys passed to `shortcode_atts()`, with the data from `$_POST` overriding the defaults.

```
Array (
    option_key_name => hello world,
    option_key_another' => foobar
)
```

You'll see I've use [input array names](http://www.johnrockefeller.net/html-input-forms-sending-in-an-array-in-php/), so as to namespace your `$_POST` data (as opposed to namespacing every option input name, then having to loop over them and remove it before saving).

**Note: This only strips out keys we don't want**. You'll probably want to go further and sanitize the individual values, dependent on their data type. If they're all the same, you could map a callback to the array and have done with it.

For example, it they're all plain text fields;

```
$options = array_map( 'wp_strip_all_tags', $options );
```